# SSIS: Save copy of package as... Prompts for package protection level in one project, not another.

Tags: ssis

Specifically, in project A when I go File -> save a copy of package as... -> I get a dialog asking me what the package location should be (File system/sql server/ssis package store), and the protection level (eg Encrypt sensitive data with user key).

On the same computer, same copy of VS2010, working on project B - when I save any packages from this project in the same way, it does not give me the above dialog, instead prompting for a location on the file system directly, with no option to encrypt sensitive data.

In project B, I can still exec these packages from the command line with dtexec/F, but I'm concerned because I'm not able to encrypt the sensitive data.

Does anyone know which setting determines which of these behaviours SSIS will use? Thanks very much.

Comment: What is the PackageProtection level of the package and optionally, the Project for when it does and does not prompt?

Comment: In project A, Project -> Properties has just one subsection; configuration properties. This does not contain a ProtectionLevel property.           In project B, Project -> Properties contains configuration properties, as well as Common Properties, which contains a ProtectionLevel property, whose value is 'EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey'.

Comment: And the ProtectionLevel on the individual packages in both projects is 'EncryptSensitiveWithUserKey'